# Select Top N Random rows from table then ordering by column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, random

I need to get 3 random rows from a table and then order those rows by a the BannerWeight column.

So if the data is:

```
BannerID     BannerWeight
   1               5
   2               5
   3               10
   4               5
   5               10
```

I want the results to be:

```
BannerID     BannerWeight
   5               10
   2               5
   4               5
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT TOP 3 b.BannerID, b.BannerWeight FROM CMS_Banner b
INNER JOIN CMS_BannerCategory c ON b.BannerCategoryID = c.BannerCategoryID
WHERE c.BannerCategoryName LIKE 'HomepageSponsors'
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I just can't figure out how to order those 3 random rows once I get them. I've tried doing

```
 ORDER BY BannerWeight, NEWID()
```

But this just gets me 3 random rows where the BannerWeight is 5.

Here is an SQLFiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8088/2/0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest option (I think) is to use a subquery:

```
Select * from 
    (
    SELECT TOP 3 b.BannerID, b.BannerWeight FROM Banners b
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) a
order by a.bannerweight
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. I just couldn't figure out the subquery